# Android Studio - Clickable CardViews inside Fragement

Tags: android-fragments, onclicklistener, android-cardview

I am new to Android Studio,

I have a "Settings Fragment" in which I have multiple CardViews (ID's: "account", "store", "bank", "Language", "User Interface", "support" etc.), however I don't know how to make it possible to click on them to open the respective activities "Account", "Store" etc.

The below code, successfully shows the various CardViews in the "Settings Fragment", however I can't figure out how to add onClickListeners. Can you help? Are there other possibilities?

Thanks alot in advance

```
package com.example.loginregister;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;


public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set click to card View same as you do with any other view . Follow some fragment sample ..

Answer (score 0):

Is it the card view as a whole that should be clickable?
Have you tried the following:

```
onClick(View v){

}
```